# How to make a custom footer lit element remain at the bottom of a page

Tags: javascript, css, lit-element

How can I make footer web component remain at the bottom of any page where it will be used? regardless of whether the content of the page is enough or not.

I have tried adding `css` properties such as `position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;` but on same pages the content goes behind the footer just remains in place.

Answer (score 0):

if you do position fixed bottom 0, you can add bottom margin/padding to the underneath element to create space so that the footer doesn't overlap the content

CSS

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.content {
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Let me try it out, I will let you know

Comment: the footer height must be the same to the margin-bottom of the content?

Comment: it doesnt have to be but it if its atleast equal youll guarentee the footer will never overlap the content